# Variable substitution in bash for loops does not work

Tags: bash

I want to run a super simple bash script that runs every file of one folder through JQ and stores it in another folder. However, for this to work, I need basic bash functionality to also work.

When I use below's bash script:

```
#/bin/bash

for file in "$1/*.json";
do
  echo "$2/$(basename $file)"
done
```

And run it on a folder containing JSON files, I will get the following result:

```
data/chu_train.json
cop_train.json
fro_train.json
ghc_train.json
got_train.json
grc_train.json
hbo_train.json
isl_train.json
lat_train.json
latm_train.json
lzh_train.json
mga_train.json
ohu_train.json
orv_train.json
san_train.json
sga_train.json
```

As can be demonstrated here, the substitution only works on the first file, and not of any of the subsequent files.
In my opinion, this would be considered a bug.

My bash version is as follows:

```
GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (arm64-apple-darwin23)
Copyright (C) 2007 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
```

What exactly is wrong with this statement that makes it execute only on the first variable?

Comment: Incorrect quoting prevents the wildcard (`*.json`) from expanding to a list of filenames until it's used as an argument to `basename`. Use `for file in "$1"/*.json` and `echo "$2/$(basename "$file")"`. [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) would've pointed these mistakes out.

Comment: As @GordonDavisson pointed, you should remove the quotes in the  for line `for file in "$1"/*.json;` , just tested and it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

for file in "$1"/*.json; do
  # Use the correct variable for constructing the output path
  outfile="$2/$(basename "$file")"

  # Execute JQ and redirect the output to the new file
  jq -r ".[].source" < "$file" > "$outfile"
done
```

Incorrect Variable Usage:

The original script used $f in the output path, which wasn't defined within the loop. It should have used the $file variable instead.
Variable Expansion Order:

Bash expands variables within double quotes (") before executing the command. This means the file\ variable would be expanded only once at the beginning of the loop, leading to the issue you observed. - To ensure correct expansion in each iteration, use command substitution (`(command)`).

Redundant cat:
The cat command was unnecessary for piping data to jq. Redirecting using < directly is more efficient.

Comment: This is not the correct solution. The echo here shows that the substitution with `$file` is incorrect. I updated the example to make it even more clear. Executing your script makes it worse. Now I get 1 global output, `"data/*json"`